# What is inside .RData file

Tags: r, rdata

I would like to investigate what is inside `.RData` file.

I tried to load `.RData` file and discovered that it consists of string:

```
load("~/Desktop/expDatDT.RData")
[1] "ret"
```

How can I obtain data about elements inside this `.RData` file?
How can I check data types for elements inside `.RData` file?

Thank you!

Comment: Reading the help page ([`?load`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/load.html)), you see that the return value (labeled `Value:`) is *"A character vector of the names of objects created, invisibly."*. This means that `"ret"` is the name of a variable within the binary data store. (It also suggests you did not copy that directly from the console, since it is returned "invisibly" and not normally printed like that.)

Comment: But @Jesse's answer stands: `str(ret)` will give you a quick view of the object named `"ret"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try,

```
load("~/Desktop/expDatDT.RData")
head(ret)
```

Also, you can check `types` using the following,

```
str(ret)
```

Let me know if it works or not!

Comment: There is nothing in the question that suggests the name of any variable within the `Rdata` file is named `expDatDT`. In fact, if it is read verbatim, there is only one object named `ret`.

Comment: It gives me the same result:

`load("~/Desktop/aml_scrna_downstream/expDatDT.RData")
head(expDatDT)
[1] "ret"
str(expDatDT)
chr "ret"`

I know that this file has multiple elements with different data types, but I do not know how to access them.

Thank you!

Comment: @OlhaKholod might need more reproducible examples to help you answer your question.

Comment: I did the following command:  
  `load("~/Desktop/expDatDT.RData", aml <- new.env())   
  ls.str(aml)`

and obtain data types from .RData file:

`ret : Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame': 69217152 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ target_id : chr  "ENST00000415118" "ENST00000434970" "ENST00000448914" "ENST00000604642" ...
 $ length    : int  8 9 13 23 19 31 31 17 23 19 ...
 $ eff_length: num  4.25 4.59 5.82 8.42 7.44 ...
 $ est_counts: num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ tpm       : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ sampleName: chr  "sample1" "sample1" "sample1" "sample1" ...`

Comment: @OlhaKholod I think this link also would be more helpful for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7270544/how-to-see-data-from-rdata-file