# What are the commands for viewing a ".RData" file's data in RStudio?

Tags: r

I am trying to find out how I can see the data within a dataset with a .RData extension.

I tried view(), it gave me one object present in the dataset but I know that this dataset is a large dataset with over 300MB size and consists of a very large number of names list. I need to view all of the contents of it and have been unsuccessful so far.

Should I convert it into a CSV instead in order to view all of the contents? If yes, how can I do that using RStudio?

Comment: Have you seen [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7270544/how-to-see-data-from-rdata-file)?  Does it answer your question?

Answer (score 3):

The cross-platform function is `View`. (Caps are discriminatory in R.) If you did:

```
 obj <- load("filename.Rdata") # assuming a file exist in your working directory
```

Then type:

```
 obj
```

You should see a print-listing of the character representations of the objects created (or possibly overwritten) in your global environment. The Rstudio aspect of this question would not affect the result.

Comment: Thank you. I was using another library which I need for this and that was causing trouble.