# Load a .RData generates a large function instead of data frame

Tags: r

I am trying to load a data frame that is in `.RData` format. I am using `load()` as is presented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7270544/how-to-see-data-from-rdata-file). When I get the object in my environment, it is loaded as a large function displaying the following output:

```
>  load("bsas_short.RData")
>  data
  function (..., list = character(), package = NULL, lib.loc = NULL, 
     verbose = getOption("verbose"), envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

I wonder why it is loading as a large `function` object instead of a `data.frame`.

Comment: ``data`` is a function in the utils package. If no other object with the same name is in the environment this function will be displayed. You could check all objects in the local environment with ``ls()``. Maybe your data is there, but has another name.

Comment: Thanks, Phann. I did that but the only object I have is data. There should be "bias_short" but does not seem to load properly.

Comment: Can save a `.RDS` of your data object?. If so, then you can import it with any desired name.

Comment: That is strange. You could try ``getAnywhere("data")`` to see all objects named ``data``. You can check the class of data with ``class(data)`` (which will probably return ``function`` as that is would you obviously see in the current environment). Maybe the ``.RData`` is broken, but I cannot reproduce that.

Comment: This was my first guess but the data it is not. I have loaded in another machine (PC) and works.

Answer (score 0):

To import the RData file and perform operations on it (such as View or other queries) do:

```
df <- get(load("bsas_short.RData"))
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcode-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.