# Modifying Tables in .RData files

Tags: r

I have an .Rdata file that contains a table. Is there any way I can edit the file to add a column to the table, and add values to this new column? I do not have the original .R file, only the .Rdata file. I'm new to R, so it would be great if I could be given a few pointers. Thanks!

Comment: u can load the .Rdata file to your R console and will try to modify the existing table with simple data manipulation codes....check the link..may be u will get small idea :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7270544/how-to-see-data-from-rdata-file

Answer (score 1):

You can load the .RData file using below code

```
load("/path/data.RData")
```

And then you can add a new column to this table using

```
cbind(data, newColumn)
```